# apache-memory-hacker-linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, hacking

We have a linux server with 4Gb of memory. When we start the system it uses only 435Mb. When we start the apache httpd services it take 1000Mb and subsequently automatically it takes all the memory and the server crashes. If we stop Apache it only releases 200Mb of memory. What could be causing this problem ?

Can any one tell me what these hacker are doing? Below is the log. Please help me out for this.

```
[root@host ~]#  tail -20 /var/log/httpd/dostizone.com-combined.log
180.76.5.143 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:16 +0530] "GET /blogs/10248/209403/nfl-panties-since-the-quality-of HTTP/1.1" 403 2298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.88 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:31 +0530] "GET /blogs/815/158725/new-jersey-attorney-search HTTP/1.1" 403 2290 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.186 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:32 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 5043 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
crawl-66-249-67-137.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:20 +0530] "GET /blogs/805/11279/supra-suprano-high-shoes HTTP/1.1" 200 30642 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
crawl-66-249-68-51.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:37 +0530] "GET /blogs/10514/215084/oakland-raiders-sweatpants-tags HTTP/1.1" 403 2297 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
220.181.94.237 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:12 +0530] "GET /profile/8509 HTTP/1.1" 200 236894 "-" "Sogou web spider/4.0(+http://www.sogou.com/docs/help/webmasters.htm#07)"
220.181.94.237 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:43 +0530] "GET /mode-switch?return_url=%2Fblogs%2F8529%2F160217%2Fclimate-jordan-6 HTTP/1.1" 302 1 "-" "Sogou web spider/4.0(+http://www.sogou.com/docs/help/webmasters.htm#07)"
crawl-66-249-68-51.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:44 +0530] "GET /blogs/390/61573/blackhawk-jerseys-from-the-you HTTP/1.1" 403 2293 "-" "SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
124.115.0.159 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:24 +0530] "GET /blogs/693/46081/application/modules/Hecore/externals/scripts/core.js HTTP/1.1" 200 26869 "http://dostizone.com/blogs/693/46081/thomas-sabo-charms-hot-chilli" "Sosospider+(+http://help.soso.com/webspider.htm)"
124.115.0.159 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:24 +0530] "GET /blogs/693/46081/application/modules/Activity/externals/scripts/core.js HTTP/1.1" 200 26873 "http://dostizone.com/blogs/693/46081/thomas-sabo-charms-hot-chilli" "Sosospider+(+http://help.soso.com/webspider.htm)"
124.115.0.159 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:24 +0530] "GET /blogs/693/46081/application/modules/Hecore/externals/scripts/imagezoom/core.js HTTP/1.1" 200 26899 "http://dostizone.com/blogs/693/46081/thomas-sabo-charms-hot-chilli" "Sosospider+(+http://help.soso.com/webspider.htm)"
180.76.5.153 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:50 +0530] "GET /blogs/10252/212268/cleveland-browns-authentic-jerse HTTP/1.1" 403 2298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
crawl-66-249-68-51.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:51 +0530] "GET /blogs/741/46260/chocolate-ugg-women-boots-1873 HTTP/1.1" 403 2293 "-" "SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
124.115.1.7 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:40 +0530] "GET /blogs/682/97454/swarovski-jewellry-sale-articles HTTP/1.1" 200 25770 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
crawl-66-249-68-51.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:56 +0530] "GET /blogs/779/60941/players-a-to-z-michael-cuddyer HTTP/1.1" 403 2293 "-" "SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
crawl-66-249-68-51.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:31:01 +0530] "GET /blogs/469/58551/chicago-bears-news-there-exist HTTP/1.1" 403 2293 "-" "SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
220.181.94.237 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:30:54 +0530] "GET /blogs/8529/160217/climate-jordan-6 HTTP/1.1" 200 30750 "-" "Sogou web spider/4.0(+http://www.sogou.com/docs/help/webmasters.htm#07)"
180.76.5.59 - - [14/Nov/2011:02:31:05 +0530] "GET /blogs/815/158197/cheap-calgary-flames-jerseys HTTP/1.1" 403 2292 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
crawl-66-249-68-51.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:31:06 +0530] "GET /mode-switch?return_url=%2Fblogs%2F387%2F45679%2Fhandbag-louis-vuitton-judy-mm-m4 HTTP/1.1" 403 2258 "-" "SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
crawl-66-249-67-137.googlebot.com - - [14/Nov/2011:02:31:10 +0530] "GET /public/temporary/c83b731ecc556d7fd1a7732d9ac16ed6.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2305 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1
```

Comment: what is the output of top -c ?

Comment: You've got your MaxClients set too high, lower it significantly (maybe only 20 to start) and see if you can keep it going with the memory usage high. I expect this is more to do with your web application that 'hacking'.

Comment: Last login: Mon Nov 14 02:01:19 2011 from 114.143.96.188
[root@host ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3922        483       3438          0         68        199
-/+ buffers/cache:        216       3705
Swap:         8189          0       8189

Comment: _Help, I'm being hacked by search engines!_ Umm, so far the ips I've looked up are relevant to Google, Baidu and SOSO. Your web server configuration needs tuning. It can't handle the load from normal operation.

Comment: First rule of detecting hacks: If you notice it, you´re not hacked. Professional Hackers are better than that.

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one tell me what these hacker are doing.

Nothing much. They're requesting a bunch of things, spaced over time, and getting either 404-not-found, or 403-not-allowed. There is one request that got 200-success, and that's for the page at `/blogs/805/11279/supra-suprano-high-shoes`. The other 200 responses are for items I'd expect you to have, like that core.js file.

The pace of requests is really low, only a few over the course of a minute. Considering those hits are coming from (what looks to me to be) spiders of various kinds, sites out there on the Internet are linking to pages that either don't exist (404) or are not visible to unauthenticated visitors (403).

As for your memory usage, considering your low hit rate, you will want to turn down your `MaxClients` and/or `ServerLimit` values in your httpd.conf. Those will consume memory.

Comment: free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3922        708       3214          0         50        534
-/+ buffers/cache:        122       3799
Swap:         8189          0       8189
top - 03:35:58 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.75, 0.24, 0.08
Tasks:  91 total,   1 running,  90 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 63.8%us,  9.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 24.0%id,  2.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4016364k total,  1921204k used,  2095160k free,    53564k buffers
Swap:  8385888k total,        0k used,  8385888k free,  1683836k cached

Comment: PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2260 mysql     15   0  283m  33m 4432 S 145.5  0.9   0:16.51 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld
 2455 apache    16   0  327m  30m  13m S  0.7  0.8   0:00.13 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2458 apache    16   0  327m  30m  13m S  0.7  0.8   0:00.12 /usr/sbin/httpd
 2457 apache    16   0  327m  30m  14m S  0.3  0.8   0:00.11 /usr/sbin/httpd
    1 root      18   0 10348  688  576 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.50 init [3]
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0

Comment: All the request are not coming from out side because in the firewall there is nor request from these ip. 5months before the hacker hack the system and they put a run some program which will genrate multiple http services but that I found and solve but this thime wht these people are doing I donot understand where is the memory going even we stop apache and mysql the memory donot go down. Once it take the memory it is nuable to rlease the memory.

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing is Linux caching all of the Apache libraries into the block-cache (the `buffers/cache` line in the free output). When figuring out how much RAM is 'free' on Linux, you take the `total` number and subtract `used` from it. Everything else is actually-free, or freeable-upon-demand and counts as free for any process asking for memory.

Comment: Look how memeory loss in 5 sec root@host ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3922       2208       1713          0         82       1710
-/+ buffers/cache:        415       3506
Swap:         8189          0       8189
[root@host ~]#
[root@host ~]#
[root@host ~]#
[root@host ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3922       2241       1680          0         82       1710
-/+ buffers/cache:        448       3473
Swap:         8189          0       8189

Comment: How can stop the hacker. Please let me known is there any solution or I need to reinstall the linux.

Comment: <IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Comment: What is the solution for this

Comment: "Once it take the memory it is nuable to rlease the memory." It's not that it's unable, it's that there's no point. Free memory does no good, it might as well not be there. Only memory that is in use helps performance. If you want free memory, take it out of the computer and put it on your desk. If you put it in the computer, the computer will *use* it. The more memory the computer uses, the faster it runs. That's why you put more memory in a computer.

Answer (score 0):

> outmatically it take all the memory and the server crase

Assuming you mean it crashes....it shouldn't. Even if all the memory is used it won't cause Apache nor the kernel to crash. The system may appear to become unresponsive due to high levels of paging - but that's not the same thing at all.

And the only reason this would happen is if you've not configured it properly.

> Can any one tell me what these hacker are doing.

I think you need to focus on getting your own stuff sorted out before you worry about what other people *might* be doing. First thing is to set up your server correctly - Switch off keepalives or reduce the tieout to 1 second, reduce the maxclients. What are your settings for maxrequestsperchild, Maxclients, Startservers, min/maxspareservers, serverlimit?

Since posting I see you've provided some of this information in a comment (should have been updated on the original question) but you've provided conditional configs depending on pre-fork / threading - which is implemented on your server?

However both configs are fairly modest - and for serving static content should not cause significant memory problems.

> even we stop the apache just it release 200mb memory

So what's still hogging all the memory? Did you check all the httpd processes had exited?